# Tableau: Switching worksheet

Tags: tableau-api

I have a tableau report that has a "Style" parameter that controls which worksheet to view. For example, if the Style="Chart" it will display the Chart worksheet, and if the Style="Summary" it will display the summary worksheet.  I got this feature working as a charm.  What if I want to add another dropdown data to the Style parameter "Both" that will display both "Chart" & "Summary". Is this possible? Can anyone provide me insights on how to accomplish this in tableau?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you filtered your worksheets by the Style parameter, you could instead filter with a formula condition.  Go to the Condition tab in the filter, and select By Formula.  Something like this may work for your Chart worksheet:

```
[Style] = 'Both' OR [Style] = 'Chart'
```

If you used something other than filters to select the appropriate worksheet, please either explain how you're doing it or share a tdx.